# Page not found using DD4T returns the error PageDAO could not be retrieved

Tags: 2013, dd4t, 2013-sp1

We are currently setting up a DD4T site I have come across an error I have not seen before.

The page is being published to the broker DB correctly. We can see XML in the PAGE_CONTENT table and reference in the PAGE table.

We have the correct publication Id set in the web.config in this case 6.

In the log file we can see DD4T trying to retrieve the page. Below is excerpt from the log file:

```
2014-08-21 11:57:27,410 DEBUG StorageManagerFactory - Loading a non cached DAO for publicationId/typeMapping/itemExtension: 6 / Page / .html
2014-08-21 11:57:27,410 ERROR PageContentAssembler - PageDAO could not be retrieved.
```

Has anyone else seen this?

Thanks

Comment: Nothing more in the logs?

Comment: Set up DD4T logging (http://blog.trivident.com/2012/08/logging-in-dd4t/) in your application as well - that can give some more clues.  Is your Storage config in your application matching up to your Deployer's? What do you see on the front end? Standard 404?

Answer (score 7):

So further looking... We found that we had copied the deployer storage_conf.xml and left in a reference to the SearchDAOBundle. Once removed everything fell into place.